# How to perform efficient log compaction for a distributed multimap where multiple commits may contribute to the state of a single <K, Set<V>> pair?

Tags: algorithm, distributed, multimap, consistency, raft

I am attempting to implement a distributed Multimap.  The map uses a state machine that is triggered whenever a commit is written to the log of the underlying cluster (raft cluster if that matters).  The issue I am coming across is in a conventional distributed map you could mark a commit for compaction once a remove command has been committed to the logs of all machines in the cluster or an update commit has been placed on a majority of nodes.  In this case multiple commits in the log can contribute to the set of values associated with a single key.  I would like to compact log entries reasonably efficiently which in my interpretation means choosing the minimal set of entries that would lead to the current state of the Multimap were the system to crash and the non compacted commits in the log replayed.

My current best solution is a greedy algorithm which chooses the commit that contributes the greatest number of values to the current state, then the commit that contributes the most to the state given that the first commit is present and so forth until a subset of commits that represents the entire current state is selected.  The unselected commits are then marked for compaction.

I was hoping someone might suggest a more efficient solution since the greedy algorithm is certainly suboptimal, it should be noted that algorithm performance matters and this processing is performed on a single thread.

Thanks!

Comment: It should be noted that each commit can add or remove an arbitrary number of values, I suspect this problem is equivalent to subset sum.

Comment: [Atomix](http://github.com/atomix/atomix) implements a `DistributedMultiMap` in a [Copycat](http://github.com/atomix/copycat) (Raft) state machine: https://github.com/atomix/atomix/blob/master/collections/src/main/java/io/atomix/collections/internal/MultiMapState.java The way it does so is pretty simple, but it sounds like your use case is complicated by commits being able to set multiple values if in reading that correctly. You want to find the smallest number of commits that equal a key's state. In that case, with performance being critical, perhaps you should opt for snapshots instead.

Comment: What I have to wonder is if this is a premature optimization. Maybe it's not. But the cost of holding too many commits in the log isn't that great unless you have a huge number of commits (a huge state machine) in which case you might need to be using a persistent state machine or something other than Raft altogether. As long as you can prevent garbage from accumulating continuously I think I'd favor using a little extra disk space to get the performance benefit (by being conservative in trying to figure out which commits need to be compacted).

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using CountDownCompleter s (a decrement-able counter with a callback when the counter hits zero) to close commits such that a commit is closed only once it no longer contributes to state, removal commit is mapped to a counter that is set based on the number of commits it removes values from and each additive commit is initialized to the number of values it adds, the additive commits decrement when one of their values is removed, and removal commits do so when an additive commit they remove from is closed.